# Convert Object to the C++ built-in type

Tags: c++-cli, type-conversion, integer-overflow

I have the following minimal code:

```
using namespace System;

long get_prop( Object^ v )
{
    return Convert::ToInt32( v );
}

int main()
{
    Object^ o1 = gcnew Int32( -1 );
    Object^ o2 = gcnew UInt32( 0xFFFFFFFF );
    long value1 = get_prop( o1 );
    long value2 = get_prop( o2 );

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the `OverflowException` exception in `get_prop` function. In the end I need to use the result of `get_prop` in pure C++ code. What is the correct way to write `get_prop` function so it can work without exception in both cases. Can I use some sort of templates as in C++ or there more trivial solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmya, you are trying to stuff a 32-bit pig in a 31-bit poke.  This code ends up calling Convert::ToInt32(UInt32 value) which looks like this:

```
public static int ToInt32(uint value)
{
    if (value > 0x7fffffff)
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
    }
    return (int) value;
}
```

Kaboom.  Not sure what kind of overflow behavior you want, but this lets the compiler do the ignoring and avoids the exception:

```
long get_prop( Object^ v )
{
    return (long)Convert::ToInt64( v );
}
```

Comment: `Convert::ToInt64` will lead to the same problem on x64 systems as I understand? As for overflow behavior I need to keep the bit-pattern of the original value.

Comment: No, a *long* is still 32-bits on MS compilers and Windows.  And a UInt32 doesn't change either.

Comment: Is there something like `static_cast` that will deal with overflows without generating exceptions? `(long)Convert::ToInt64` looks unsafe still.

Comment: There's no difference between static_cast and a C cast here.  Conquer your fear by actually running this in 64-bit mode.  This post will self-destruct in 6 seconds, clearly it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I'm not too close with C++/CLI as with pure C++. Silly questions from that.